# Character [hex] to integer

Tags: c

I tried using atoi function to do this, but it didn't work.

I want to convert a string that says "0x44" to an integer (as 0x44 or its decimal equivalent).

Does anyone know of any functions that could do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Use `strtol` instead, and specify 0 as the base.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() {
  char* hex = "0x44";
  int i;

  sscanf( hex, "%x", &i );
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: I provided this solution as well, but deleted it since malformed input like `0x44z` will be treated as `0x44`, and this may not be desired.

Comment: Not only that, but `scanf` is notoriously hard to use correctly (given sufficiently malformed input, `i` would fail to get initialised, in this case), and also I think the OP wants different behaviour depending on whether the `0x` or `0` prefix is present or not.

Comment: I thought the starting question was how to convert "0x44" to an integer... I guess I was wrong.